# Why is dark matter and dark energy needed to explain why there's more and less gravity respectively than there should be?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter, dark-energy

Why is [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) needed to account for that there's more gravity than there should be, and [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) for that there's less gravity than there should be?

Obviously that can't be correct, but I'm unable to find a much more precise definition and description of how we know it exists. (An answer that answers this question might go into how dark matter and dark energy have uneven distributions or effects. This would explain why the value of gravity couldn't be lowered or raised to eliminate one of them--though even this doesn't necessarily explain anything, as said in the next paragraph.)

Also what is it that means there's dark matter and energy, instead of that the definition of gravity is wrong? Why can't it just consistently act differently in different kinds of situations?

Answer (score 1):

In mainstream physics models there are [four forces](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hyperphysics%20fundamental%20forces) that describe all the available data and observations, based on the [standard model of particle physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

In the astrophysical observations there are observations  that are being explained by the introduction of dark matter, and dark energy.

Dark matter is needed to explain the rotational curves of galaxies, because the luminous mass of galaxies cannot fit their trajectories. It is called [**dark matter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter)  because there is no electromagnetic radiation coming from where the extra mass should be to fit the equations. There are many candidate hypothesis , from small masses like meteorites to new particles that are being searched in accelerator experiments.

[Dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) is

> an unknown form of energy that affects the universe on the largest scales. The first observational evidence for its existence came from supernovae measurements, which showed that the universe does not expand at a constant rate; rather, the expansion of the universe is accelerating.

It is necessary to keep using mainstream physics in modeling the universe and its evolution.

> Also what is it that means there's dark matter and energy, instead of that the definition of gravity is wrong.

The mainstream [Big bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) explains astrophysical observations by the inclusion of dark energy and dark matter in a satisfactory way. There exist efforts at introducing  models , with modified gravity, but they are not mainstream at present.

Comment: So the distribution of dark matter is densest on the outer edges of galaxies? And there isn't dark energy and matter in our calculations on Earth, so there isn't any in the inner area of galaxies?

Comment: It is a matter of strength of the gravitational forces, they have large effects for large accumulations of masses, but at the level of our planetary locations the numbers are very very small. The same holds true for expansion, it is only on cosmological scales that an effect is noticeable

Comment: No, the density of dark matter in galaxies is denser towards the center of the galaxy. There is dark matter here on Earth too, at a density of about 300 proton masses per liter. The Hubble expansion in gravitationally bound systems such as Earth (or the Milky Way) is overcompensated for by that gravitational bound, so we can not measure it (or dark energy) near Earth.

Comment: @rfl Can you explain "The Hubble expansion in gravitationally bound systems such as Earth (or the Milky Way) is overcompensated for by that gravitational bound, so we can not measure it (or dark energy) near Earth."

Comment: @anna v, no, the relevant values would be exactly the same. It would be the same value of gravity times a very small amount.

Comment: @user84614  I am not saying the opposite, I am just saying  the effect would be too small to measure it on earthor the solar planetary system

Comment: @user84614  you should ask rtf  300 protons per litter compared to avogadros number , ~$10^{23}$  per mole means zero

Comment: @user84614, gravitationally bound objects do not participate in the expansion of the universe. For example, our galaxy doesn't grow. Or, the distance to the Andromeda Galaxy doesn't increase, it actually decreases.

Comment: @annav yes, there isn't much dark matter around here compared to all that normal matter. But that's just because our planet is a highly unusual place in the universe. And I figured it's relevant since you /can/ search for dark matter on Earth using lab experiments, that's called "direct dark matter detection".

Comment: @user84614 "Direct detection experiments search for events induced by particles from the Milky Way’sdark matter halo."  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.03026.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "Dark" matter and energy are rather confusing names. Really those two things have nothing in common other than that word "dark". "Dark matter" isn't even dark, it's transparent. With respect to "dark" energy, that's really just figuratively in a sense that we are currently in the dark as to its roots. Silly names. Perhaps this already explains some of the confusion.

Concerning dark matter: Rotation curves of galaxies is really just one of many independent observations that require dark matter as an explanation. It just means that apparently we observe more gravity than you would expect based on the observed mass. So, we observe various systems, be it galaxies, galaxy clusters, large scale structure, the universe as a whole at various times, etc, and in all cases the measured gravitational force is stronger than what we would calculate based on the mass that we can observe in those systems, using Newton's gravity or Einstein's general relativity.

In that situation we have two possibilities to proceed. One, gravity in those systems for some unknown reason could be stronger that we'd expect (based on those theories). That's called "modified gravity". However, no theory of modified gravity has been proposed that could explain all of the many astrophysical and cosmological observations.

Alternatively, we can assume that there is additional matter that is invisible and so far has eluded our detection. That matter could then cause the additional, observed gravitational force. "Dark matter" is simply the name for that hypothesis. It's actually quite natural to think of when you look at the history of astrophysics and particle physics, where we kept discovering new particles over the last 120 years.

Dark energy behaves different than what you would expect simply from less gravity. It refers to the observed fact that the acceleration of space is accelerating. Dark energy is not distributed like mass, and can thus not be explained by modifying the gravitational strength, or assuming less mass present, or there being "less gravity". Instead, it is a property of spacetime itself. I find it less confusing (though more clumsy ;) ) to keep saying "accelerated expansion of space" instead of dark energy.

So you see, dark matter and dark energy are really two unrelated things.

Comment: @rflI'm afraid that on dark matter at least, you expressed the exact idea that made me ask this question."apparently we observe more gravity than you would expect based on the observed mass.So, we observe various systems, be it galaxies, galaxy clusters, large scale structure, the universe as a whole at various times, etc, and in all cases the measured gravitational force is stronger than what we would calculate based on the mass that we can observe in those systems"That is a superfluous and meaningless explanation.Do you mean that the force is stronger between large systems than within them?

Comment: Woha. Not very polite. Thank you for requesting an edit to my answer (that correctly got rejected by others) and, in addition, calling my answer "superfluous". How friendly. My answer explains what dark matter is, and how it relates to requiring "more gravity" in places where we observe mass. Yes, the observed gravitational attraction between e.g. galaxies or galaxy clusters is larger than what we would expect based on observed matter alone. Yes also, the observed gravitational attraction within e.g. galaxies is stronger too. By different amounts, but some effect is seen in all those systems.

Comment: Sorry for that, my comment was limited by the word limit